# parsing the JSON structure with backslash

Tags: json, primefaces

The front end recieves the json output in the following format (with a backslash before the double quote). We didn't intentionally put the backspace but Primefaces(JSF) does when sending the output to front end. How to parse this and save it in an array using jquery or javascript? We don't want the backslash added by primefaces at all, if there is way we can do from the server side (Primefaces) please let me know. We can remove the "\" using some function in javascript but then it may remove any backslash if we gave it intentionaly. For example if i am sending double string like \"foo\"

```
{"topicJSON":"{\"topicBody\":[\"Test10\",\"Test22\",\"Test4\",\"Test11\"]}"}
```

Server Side

```
jGenerator.writeFieldName("topicBody");             jGenerator.writeStartArray();                  ...............             jGenerator.close();              context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();           
 context.addCallbackParam("topicJSON", out.toString());
```

Comment: try var newOne = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsOldVariable);//yourJsOldVariable contains that string you posted

Comment: @Daniel thanks it is working. You might need to turn your comment as answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.parseJSON`

like this

```
var newOne = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsOldVariable);//yourJsOldVariable contains that string you posted
```