# Primefaces callback sending JSON data with '&' fails

Tags: jquery, json, primefaces

During testing,primefaces fails if the HTTP response with JSON data contains '&', if i remove '&' it works. The data i am sending is an URL,do i need to send the url in encode format? Will this issue happens if any data (which is not url) contains 'amp' or any kind of such character? What is the best approach in that case.

## commandlink with callback

```
<h:form prependId="false" id="getAllTopics" style="display:none;">
        <p:commandLink action="#{topicController.listAllTopics}" id="topicListAllCmdLink" value=""
            oncomplete="javascript:renderTopic(xhr, status,args)" />
    </h:form>
```

## JS function

```
function renderTopic(xhr,status,args){
        jsonArray=[];
        console.log(args.topicJSON);
        jsonArray = $.parseJSON(args.topicJSON);
   .....
}
```

Respone from Google developer kit

```
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[4297043168621098325:5437886159631978839]]></update><extension ln="primefaces" type="args">{"topicJSON":"[{\"topicBody\":\"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3ZyU98N3Fk&feature=relmfu \",\"videoAudioUrl\":\"\",\"topicGuid\":5600,\"userGuid\":0,\"imageURL\":\"\",\"topicOwnUserName\":\"srikanth marni\",\"topicCommentList\":[],\"topicUpdateTime\":1346817736000}]"}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

## Error in Console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'topicJSON' of undefined circle_topic.js.jsf:150
renderTopic circle_topic.js.jsf:150
PrimeFaces.ab.oncomplete circle.jsf:175
k.complete primefaces.js.jsf:1
b.Callbacks.bv jquery.js.jsf:16
b.Callbacks.bE.fireWith jquery.js.jsf:16
bF jquery.js.jsf:23
b.ajaxTransport.send.bv
```

Comment: your **Fail** works fine for me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pb2q/8MSTM/)

Comment: @pb2q you are right it is not problem with json parser, primefaces is not able to parse it for some reason as the data comes through it.

Comment: Seems that backslashes are the problem. see here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196148/parsing-the-json-structure-with-backslash?rq=1

Comment: @Heidarzadeh Primefaces is not able to send response if it as "&" from server side. When i debug it from front end, the 'status; of response  is showing as parseException. It is the primefaces which giving issue.

Answer (score 0):

currently (v.5.2) the primefaces partial response writer does not escape JSON for XML which causes problems with characters '<', '>', '&' and so on.

For getting this working, I patched the method encodeCallbackParams
in org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter as follows, whereas XML is org.json.XML:

```
private void encodeCallbackParams(Map<String, Object> params) throws IOException, JSONException {

if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {

    startExtension(CALLBACK_EXTENSION_PARAMS);
    write("{");

    for (Iterator<String> it = params.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String paramName = it.next();
    Object paramValue = params.get(paramName);

    if (paramValue instanceof JSONObject) {
        String json = ((JSONObject) paramValue).toString();
        json = XML.escape(json);
        write("\"");
        write(paramName);
        write("\":{");
        write(json.substring(1, json.length() - 1));
        write("}");
    } else if (paramValue instanceof JSONArray) {
        String json = ((JSONArray) paramValue).toString();
        json = XML.escape(json);
        write("\"");
        write(paramName);
        write("\":[");
        write(json.substring(1, json.length() - 1));
        write("]");
    } else if (isBean(paramValue)) {
        String json = new JSONObject(paramValue).toString();
        json = XML.escape(json);
        write("\"");
        write(paramName);
        write("\":");
        write(json);
    } else {
        String json = new JSONObject().put(paramName, paramValue).toString();
        json = XML.escape(json);
        write(json.substring(1, json.length() - 1));
    }

    if (it.hasNext()) {
        write(",");
    }
    }

    write("}");
    endExtension();
}
}
```

Comment: if you patch it with an additional param (so default behaviour is backwards compatible) you can submit a pull request in github... Benefits everybody then!

Comment: this issue is already reported to primefaces, but may take a while for being included in the next release...

Comment: That is why I mentioned to create a full patch and pull request as described above. It will speed up things…  the current PF issuelist in google is not enough